# Composer script - run only sometimes

Tags: php, composer-php

In my composer.json I have a script called tests that is just an array of several commands for testing tools.

One of those commands is pretty slow and somewhat unimportant. So I would like to run it only occasionally and not always (whole composer tests is run as pre-commit hook)

I had an idea of doing something like

```
"scripts": {
   "slowScript": "rand(0,10) != 5 || actualSlowScript"
}
```

but I can't get it to work. The script needs to be platform independent as we use different OS.

Do you have an idea on how to get it working?

Comment: Can you move the logic for "sometimes" into your script? Then just run your script always and have it terminate randomly on its own?

Comment: Composer does not have (nor it makes much sense it had) such feature. As Chris says, if you want to have something like that, handle it in `actualSlowScript` directly.

Comment: It's a library so I cannot edit it directly. Writing some encapsulating script would be possible but that feels like complex solution to simple problem. [Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) refers to custom php commands in scripts but I was unable to get the value out of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution:

Create a PHP class with static method as in https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts

```
<?php

namespace ComposerScripts;

use Composer\Console\Application;
use Composer\Script\Event;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;

final class RandomLint
{
    public static function runLintAtRandom(Event $event): void
    {
        $random = random_int(1, 5);

        if ($random === 1) {
            $event->getIO()->write('Lint skipped');
            return;
        }

        $input = new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'lint'));
        $application = new Application();
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        $application->run($input);
    }
}
```

then define the script as

```
"scripts": {
    
    "test": [
      "ComposerScripts\\RandomLint::runLintAtRandom",
      "secondScript",
      "@thirdOne"
    ]
  }
```

and you can control scripts from PHP Class. I can see quite some potential in this solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would not build it into the test script because then you can never force the test to run when you want, like in a build pipeline. You can do it via the composer scripts feature by using the exit status of a shell command:

```
"scripts": {
   "slowScript": "[ $(rand -M 5) -eq 0 ] && actualSlowScript"
}
```

Assuming you have the `rand` command installed, this picks a random number between 0 and 4, then only runs the test if it picked 0.

Note this will throw a composer warning 80% of the time. If that's problematic, you could do something like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "slowScript": "if [ $(rand -M 5) -eq 0 ]; then actualSlowScript; else echo skipping slow test; fi"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but sadly it doesn't work. Even the check alone ends with error code 1

Comment: What doesn't work? It runs ok for me. If you do `"slowScript": "true && actualSlowScript"` does it run every time?

Comment: You might have to adjust the syntax for your shell if you're not running bash.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know in what environment it will run so it needs to be as generic as possible.

Comment: Well you know you have PHP available, you could use: `"slowScript": "php -r 'if(rand(1,5)>1)exit(1);' && actualSlowScript"`

Comment: I tried that but exit(1) makes the whole chain of command fail with error